# How to use HTTPS to reach localhost?

Tags: react-native, react-native-ios

I am involved in a React-Native project which is about to go in production. Our client put our code to Fortify and found out that we have insecure HTTP connections. However it is only because of React-Native's connection to the localhost which I think in default uses HTTP.

[image]

Are there any ways to change this default property so that React-Native talks to the localhost more securely, i.e. using HTTPS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can remove that exception when creating the bundle that will go for production since the react-native server won't be used.

Comment: First I tried removing ATS flag and run on simulator with debug mode, and it created problem. Second I removed the ATS flag completely and bundled, as you said, locally before installing to phone and worked fine. Latter is the case for production, thank you @Eldelshell.